Solving integral involving minimum $\int_{L^n} \bigwedge_{j=1}^n \Big( \sum_{k=1}^j x_k \Big) \ dx$.
Consider $L = [s,t]$ with $s<t$ and write $a \wedge b := \text{min}(a,b)$. I am trying to solve the following integral.
$$
\int_{L^n} \bigwedge_{j=1}^n \Big( \sum_{k=1}^j x_k \Big) \ dx
$$
My approach so far was to split it over the regions $G_j := \{x\in\mathbb{R}^n 
 \,|\,\forall i: \sum_{k \leq j} x_k \leq \sum_{k\leq i} x_k\}$ like so:
\begin{align*}
\int_{L^n} \bigwedge_{j=1}^n \Big( \sum_{k=1}^j x_k \Big) \ dx &= \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^j \int_{L^n \cap G_j} x_k\ dx
\end{align*}
However parameterizing $L^n \cap  G_j$ in a way that can easily be integrated over proved quite difficult for me. Any help with this is appreciated!
